# Determining homography from known planes?

Tags: computer-vision, transformation, homography

I've got a question related to multiple view geometry.

I'm currently dealing with a problem where I have a number of images collected by a drone flying around an object of interest. This object is planar, and I am hoping to eventually stitch the images together.

Letting aside the classical way of identifying corresponding feature pairs, computing a homography and warping/blending, I want to see what information related to this task I can infer from prior known data.

Specifically, for each acquired image I know the following two things: I know the correspondence between the central point of my image and a point on the object of interest (on whose plane I would eventually want to warp my image). I also have a normal vector to the plane of each image.

So, knowing the **centre point** (in object-centric world coordinates) and the **normal**, I can derive the plane equation of each image.

**My question is, knowing the plane equation of 2 images is it possible to compute a homography (or part of the transformation matrix, such as the rotation) between the 2?**

I get the feeling that this may seem like a very straightforward/obvious answer to someone with deep knowledge of visual geometry but since it's not my strongest point I'd like to double check...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "normal" is the direction of the focal axis of the camera.

So, IIUC, you have a 3D point that projects on the image center in both images, which is another way of saying that (absent other information) the motion of the camera consists of the focal axis orbiting about a point on the ground plane, plus an arbitrary rotation about the focal axis, plus an arbitrary translation along the focal axis.

The motion has a non-zero baseline, therefore the transformation between images is generally not a homography. However, the portion of the image occupied by the ground plane does, of course, transform as a homography.

Such a motion is defined by 5 parameters, e.g. the 3 components of the rotation vector for the orbit, plus the the angle of rotation about the focal axis, plus the displacement along the focal axis. However the one point correspondence you have gives you only two equations.

It follows that you don't have enough information to constrain the homography between the images of the ground plane.